# redis lrange prefix fetching way

Tags: python, redis

I have list type data in redis, there're so many keys which can't be fetched all one time. I tried to use python redis Lrange function to get in batch style, such as 1000 a time, but it seems not work as it always return empty. Lrange regard `*` as a character, how should I do it?

```
conn.Lrange(f'test-{id}-*', 0, 1000)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`conn.lrange()` and the underlying Redis [`LRANGE` command](https://redis.io/commands/lrange/) returns the elements of a given set, not the keys of a database: your code returns an empty array because the given key does not exist.

To retrieve the keys of a database you should use the [`SCAN` command](https://redis.io/commands/scan/), exposed by [`conn.scan()`](https://github.com/redis/redis-py/blob/master/redis/commands/core.py#L2935).